# Select based on Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql

All,
Say I have the following data set:

```
id     docId        meta_key    meta_value
1    356          rating           2.0
2    356     total_votes            10
3    356    total_rating           200
```

Basically I'm trying to pull all the values in my meta_value column by selecting the docId of 356 and only selecting the meta_key rows that I have listed.

Any ideas how to do this in a single query?

EDIT: My desired output would be something like this:

`rating     total_votes    total_rating
2.0        10             200`

I'm trying to get it so that I can use these values with a mysql_fetch_array in PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "pull all the values in meta_value" but "only select meta_key"? Please provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I updated my question with the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is a [pivot table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table). Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't provide functions for generating pivot tables.

It's still doable, but with more than two columns, it starts to get messy.

I would loop through the records in PHP and build the array.

To borrow slightly from Ghost Developer's answer:

```
$assoc_array = array();
$query = "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM table WHERE docId=356";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $assoc_array[$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

All columns from all rows for docId 356

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE docId = 356;
```

Only the meta_value column from all rows for docId 356

```
SELECT meta_value FROM mytable WHERE docId = 356;
```

Get all values as a comma-separated list for docId 356

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) meta_values FROM mytable WHERE docId = 356;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE docId=356");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $metaKey = $result['meta_key'];
    $meta_value = $result['meta_value'];
    echo $meta_key.' : '.$meta_value.'<br>';
}
```